# Passing span classes to data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I am after some assistance in passing the value of my span classes to a data attribute `(data-groups)` contained in their parent divs all with the same class `(.item)`. Here is my current code.

```
<div class="item" href="#" data-groups="">
   <div class="caption">
      <p><span class="value1"></span>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item" href="#" data-groups="">
   <div class="caption">
      <p><span class="another-value"></span>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item" href="#" data-groups="">
   <div class="caption">
      <p><span class="third-value"></span>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".item").attr("data-groups", function() {
  return $('.caption p span').attr('class');
});
</script>
```

This works somewhat but it populates all `data-groups` attributes with `"value1"`. I am wanting them all to receive the data attribute from their respective child span classes. Eg, First item div should have a `'data-groups'`attribute of `'value1',` second with `'another-value',` etc.

I'm a little rusty with jquery but learning as I go. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: try ` $(this).find('.caption p span').attr('class')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".item").attr("data-groups", function() {
  return $(this).find('.caption p span').attr('class');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple